# Connecting to sqlite file went wrong from one day to another on Win7

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

On a Windows 7 machine I have an sqlite db, that connects to my .net/c# app. In that app I connect to this db by a very simple `var connection = new SQLiteConnection(connString);` command.

It worked for a year, but from today it has started to throw 'Unable to open database file' exception. Nothing has changed on that machine, except there were some automatic win updates, nothing more.

The file did not become corrupt, it can be opened by coomand line and sqlite gui apps. The security settings were not changed on that machine.

I know several topics with this sqlite error message, but this problem seems to be a new one.

So, does anybody have a bug like this after some windows 7 automatic update process?

**Update**: beside win7 update, there were some Avast Antivirus updates during the night. So these two updates happened after the last successful connection.

Comment: Did you check that the database file is still there and has the correct security settings?

Comment: Yes, and it can be opened by any sqlite guy admin apps, by that user. And the folder has read/write permissions and did not changed today.

Comment: Which version of SQLite.Data are you using?

Answer (score 0):

So, finally we found, it was caused by Avast AntiVirus.

If anybody would have such a problem, check the antivirus settings, carantene, sandbox & co.